# Inputting Recorded Video File from Webcam Access in PHP Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've been trying to run my code where i am trying to upload a video file to my php database with the current userid in the user_data table. But then, i didn't met the first condition in my php code, and also yes the record option is doing its job but it doesn't upload to the directory folder Upload/ or in the database, and that is where i was searching for answer

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'conn.php';

$allowedExtensions = array('.mp4');
$path = 'Uploads/';

if (isset($_FILES['video'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['video'];
    $extension = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    if (!in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
        die('Invalid Data Type. ');
    }

    if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die('Upload Failed with Error' . $file['error']);
    }

    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload (userid, filename) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $user_id, $filename);
    $stmt->execute();

    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path . '/' . $filename . '-' . $extension);

    echo "File uploaded successfully.";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
echo "error";
  exit();
?>
```

This is my script connected by XMLHttpRequest, where the function of recording on my Webcam access:

```
const video = document.getElementById('videoElement');
const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
let mediaRecorder;
let chunks = [];

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
      .then(stream => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log('Recording started.');
        
        // Add event listeners for media recorder
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
          chunks.push(event.data);
        });
        
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
          const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' });
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('video', blob, 'recording.mp4');
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'view.php');
          xhr.send(formData);
        });
      });
  });
  
  stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    console.log('Recording stopped.');
  });
};
```

for information this is my html where i store my button and the video player for the webcam:

```
<div id="container">
               <video id="videoElement" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted>
        
               </video>
        </div>

        </div>
        </article>
        <div class="side">
            <h3><center>CONTROLS</h3>
                <!-- latest na nagawa -->
                <button class="startButton" id="start">Start Recording</button>
                <button class="stopButton" id="stop">Stop Recording</button>
        </div>
```

My problem here is that i didn't met the first condition in my php, any idea is welcome

I tried debugging it by calling *echo "Error"* at my php and yes it echo at the end code of my php where i didn't met the `if (isset($_FILES['video']))` condition

Comment: You are not using the `FILES` array - you are just sending a POST request, perhaps `$_POST['video']`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thank You for advice, but did it, still same problem. it won't let me go to the view.php and stay at my homepage, but nothing happens on the upload process

Comment: I tried to emulate your code ( without the `faceapi.nets` stuff and changed HttpRequest to Fetch ) and I was able to access `$_POST['video']` on my server, part of the content received was `"------WebKitFormBoundaryERlJ7RA2CItzyhiC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"; filename="recording.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4"`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes Thank You for the efforts and knowledge, i have solved my problem earlier it was just the path and yes the file arrays, i have taken your advice and so thankful at the same time, Thank You Again, have a Good Day Ahead :))